# Invalid account name creating scheduled task, Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, scheduled-tasks, windows-error-reporting

I have previously used the Task Scheduling plus shortcut workaround to avoid the UAC prompt when running my podcast aggregator, Juice, but recently it has not been working.  I tried to go into the Task Scheduler today to recreate the scheduled task, but got this error:

> An error has occurred for task Reminders - (name).  Error message: The specified account name is not valid.

I am working in an administrator account, in Windows 7.

Guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try to run **Task Scheduler** as Administrator

Comment: Thank you.  Oddly, when I go to Control Panel > System and Security > Administrative Tools, the folder appears to be empty.  When I stop one step earlier (before clicking on Administrative Tools), I can *see* "Schedule tasks," but I can't right-click on it to be able to do "Run as administrator."

Comment: in your start menu, search for it and right click...run as administrator

Answer (score 0):

It turned out there was one task that was "queued" as opposed to "ready."  In other words it was invalid.  The error message was a cryptic effort to let me know that something in the set of scheduled tasks was not right.

When I deleted the problematic task, I stopped getting the error message.